# MPLAB/XC8 can't jump in ASM?

Tags: c, assembly, pic

I have a project for the PIC18F25K50 of mixed C and Assembly; most of what I want to do I can easily manage (and must for efficiency) in Assembly, but some parts where I care more about ease of development use C. I actually have a couple of these, and I keep encountering the same issue: I can't use ASM to jump to a label. Every single function to jump - `CALL`, `GOTO`, `BNC`, and so on - will fail if given a label, setting PC to some random-but-consistent value where there are no instructions, causing the program to hang. Using an address works fine: `BC $+4` skips the next line.

An example of what does not work is this:

```
#asm
_waitUS:
    GLOBAL  _waitUS
waitLoop:
    //12 cycles = 1 microsecond:
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    NOP
    DECFSZ  WREG, F, ACCESS
    GOTO waitLoop
    RETURN
#endasm

void main() {
    //DEBUG:
    waitUS(6);
}
```

Now, this may not work overall, and I am **begging** you to focus on the issue of jumping - this is still in  prototyping because I can't even get the function called. The program does compile without issue.

As soon as `waitUS(6)` is called, the PC jumps from - in my case - `0x7C96` to `0x52`. Swapping the C call out for `MOVLW 6; CALL _waitUS` breaks in exactly the same way.

If I strictly use C for calling/jumping (as I had to in the previous project), it works fine, and figures out where it's going.

I've been searching for an answer to this for a few weeks now, and still haven't seen anyone else with this problem, even though every project I make (including plaintext in notepad, compiling via command line) has the exact same issue. What the heck is up with this?

**Edit:** Having discovered the program memory view, I was able to get a better idea of what it's doing. The compiler *does* know where the functions are, and it *is* trying to jump to the right location. Apparently, CALL just doesn't know where it's going.

Example:
Address `0x7C92` contains `CALL 0x2044, 0`. That is precisely what it ought to, that is where the desired function starts. However, upon running this instruction, `PC` is altered to **0x205E**, missing half of the function.

Attempting to be clever, I decided to tack on several NOPs to the start of the function after its label, lining the real code up with `0x205E`. Unfortunately, it seems any change alters where its unpredictable jumping will land, and it then landed at `0x2086` instead.

Incidentally, when it starts running at random places, it will often run across a `GOTO` - and it *will* jump to the specified location as intended. This only works within the same function, as trying to use `GOTO` instead of `CALL` ends up in the same incorrect location, despite what the compiled result demands.

Answer (score -1):

The PDF document at http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/33014K.pdf has many examples on how to code the PIC18.

Here is one such example:

```
RST CODE 0x0 ;The code section named RST
    ;is placed at program memory
    ;location 0x0. The next two
    ;instructions are placed in
    ;code section RST.
    pagesel start ;Jumps to the location labelled
    goto start ;’start’.

PGM CODE ;This is the beginning of the
    ;code section named PGM. It is
    ;a relocatable code section
    ;since no absolute address is
    ;given along with directive CODE.
start
    movlw D'10'
    movwf delay_value
    xorlw 0x80
    call delay
    goto start
    end
```

Comment: That doesn't really address the question. Clearly, I know how to format a CALL or GOTO instruction. The issue is why that instruction doesn't go to the specified location.